# How to override export_data() in odoo?

Tags: python, export, overriding, odoo-8

I'm trying to override export_data() in res_partner. I inherited it (In 5 modules, I don't know if it can cause trouble for this), and in my last module, I try to redefine "export_data()". I did :

```
def export_data(self, cr, uid, ids, fields_to_export, context=None):
    super(res_partner, self).export_data(cr, uid, ids, fields_to_export, context=context)
```

I still did nothing particular in it because this is already making an error.

```
TypeError: export_data() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'
```

I don't think it might change anything but I also redifine search just above and it works correctly.

If I remove "context=None", I get the error :

```
TypeError: export_data() takes exactly 5 arguments (7 given)
```

(I'm only removing this single argument, not two)
And I get the exact same error if I remove "self" or "ids".

Do someone has an exemple of export_data() override? I only found answers about how to redefine and it is telling to do exactly what I'm doing, but I never seen it in a real module. Might it be a problem of version? How do you do it in Odoo-8?

The problem come from the first line

```
def export_data(self, cr, uid, ids, fields_to_export, context=None):
```

Because if I write a pdb.set_trace() just under it, it's never reached.

I tried to give all the information that might help, if you need more, tell me.

Comment: Check the input at line where the export_data is called, if needed put pdb.set_trace() before, not inside the method. Also check if you have used correct decorator

Comment: I tryed decorators models, return, one, multi and every time had an error. What to you mean by checking the input? With the pdb.set_trace() or is that something else?

Comment: I added the pbd.set_trace() just before the def export_data(...) but it still give me the error "multiple context" before I see the pdb.set_trace()

Comment: How do you call the method? In the Python code or on the button press?

Comment: On the button press (not a new one, just the same button press I'd use without the redefinition)
By the way, I'll have to export without any new parameter if their is not only one specific field to export, but I guess I can check that with "fields_to_export"